# What is my.cnf.migrated?

Tags: 16.04, mysql, do-release-upgrade

I'm preparing to upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04, and I have a custom mysql `my.cnf` file. It sounds like at the end of *do-release-upgrade*, I'll end up with a `my.cnf` file and a `my.cnf.migrated` file.

1. If I understand correctly, after the upgrade, the `my.cnf` file will be *exactly* as I left it, but the config file mysql will be using will be the `my.cnf.migrated` file, which will be a best guess at auto-migrating my custom config. Is this correct?
2. After double-checking `my.cnf.migrated`, can I just rename `my.cnf.migrated` to `my.cnf`, discarding the old version, and be good to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2. Maybe. MySQL might have nuked older options you used and error out if you re-activate them. Take the safe option by comparing the 2 1st and eye-ball the differences (`diff my.cnf my.cnf.migrated`)
3. Yes.

---

In case you also have a `my.cnf.fallback` the same applies to this one.

Comment: Is there any place where these different files and what they contain is documented?

Comment: I have not seen any docs on this. This though explains a bit: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mysql-5.6/+bug/1447944 (see the comments). and here some code that uses it: https://github.com/ltangvald/mysql-5.7/blob/master/debian/mysql-common.preinst